# How to know when certain Ajax call has completed?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

I am programming a timesheet that contains several timers. When I add a new timer, it both creates html to show the timer  and sends out an Ajax put request to create the timer record on the server. then when the Ajax call completes I use the record id in the response and input that into the html. I have programming set up where if I click start on any timer, it will stop any running clock by taking the record of that clock and sending it to the server. I need to handle the situation for when someone clicks stop on a timer while a newly added timer is waiting for the record id from the server. I looked into ajaxComplete, but I am hoping for something more direct instead of a catch all for all running Ajax requests. I don’t think Promise.all() can work because the programming to create and receive a record id is contained within its own function. I was hoping to do something similar to a Promise.all(ajaxOfPutRequest), but this ajaxOfPutRequest is called outside the stopTimer function. Here is the relevant code:

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
  var createRecord = () => {
    $(this).parent().addClass('toggled')
    //collect data from element
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      data: data,
      success: function (response) {
        $(this).attr('id', response.record.id)
      },
      error: function () {}
    })
  }
  createRecord()
})

$('stopTimerButton').on('click', function () {
  var stopTimer = () => {
    $('#' + idOfRunningClock).each(function () {
      //collect data
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'PUT',
        headers: headers,
        data: data,
        success: function () {
          Knack.hideSpinner();
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

See how are the functions are separate? They don't stem from same eventListener, and I don't know how to make second function wait for first function to complete, since second function depends on data (the record Id) of the first function. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think we need to see relevant code to better understand the problem and potential solutions.

Comment: You say you need to handle the situation for when someone clicks STOP (while ...) but you have only described the START action.
It's not clear how a STOP action is supposed to behave or what the consequences are of there being a "latent" new timer when STOP is clicked.

Comment: Seems a safe strategy would be 
(i) to display timers only *after* an id has been returned from the server; 
(ii) to initialise new timers in the *stopped* state.